# How to get the recent folders, my projects and my favorite documents from SharePoint online/ Office 365 using Graph API

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

Is there any way to get the recent folders, my projects, my favorite documents from SharePoint online/ Office 365 using Graph API ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a variety of insight based APIs based on activity in Microsoft 365. They are docoumented here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/officegraphinsights?view=graph-rest-1.0

To answer your question
- recent folders - the /me/insights/used will give you Documents. But not folders. But you could use the response from this API and then make a consolidated list of parent folders.
- my projects - what do you mean by "my projects"?
- my favorite docs - favorite docs is a Delve construct in that UI only. I do not believe that we make this available in our API. There is a notion of Favorite Sites and you can use the followed API to do this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/site-follow?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

Comment: My project - this would be either project site or ms project(project professional ).

Comment: Favourite Documents - cant this be retrieved from delve!